# creating different instances of view controller from storyboard with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am instantiate view controller from storyboard. I would like to new a new instance of view controller every time I call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. It doesn't do what I want, instead, it always return the same view controller instance. I guess instead of using storyboard, I should create the view controller programatically. Before I dive into that, is it really not possible to ask a new view controller instance from story board?

EDIT: I was wrong about this behaviour, apparently storyboard behaves exactly like I would expect, i.e., instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier does return a new instance every time.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit strange: from the [official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it is mentioned: 
**`This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it`**. 
Are you 100% sure the same instance is return each time you call this method.

Otherwise yes you would need to instanciate explicitly your custom view controller.

Comment: thanks tiguero, you are correct. It does create a new instance every time I call it. Not sure why I saw same address last time.